# Deploy unreal engine 4 game html5

Tags: html, heroku

I’ve been trying to post my game on heroku for several days now.
I did everything on this tutorial, as well as several similar videos on youtube.

- https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Basics/Projects/Packaging/index.html

Locally, everything works fine on my machine. But when I try to run on another computer or put it on heroku - it comes to Launching engine and it lasts forever.
[Here is the errors devtools gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynohz.png)

I suspect that something is missing on the machines that I ran.

Repo link: https://github.com/ice8scream/playground/tree/master/public/games/buildingescape

Heroku link: https://ices-playground.herokuapp.com/buildingescape/

I also read this article:

- https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Deployment/BuildOperations/index.html
- [And got these 3 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86qyR.png),[pak file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYq6r.png),[Font files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6DUo.png)
  But I did not understand what to do with them and where to put them.
  I was completely stuck, re-read many forums, but could not find the answer.

Maybe someone came across a similar one. Or knows how to solve this problem.

It’s very disappointing that I can’t start the game on the server and show it to someone (

Thanks in advance for your replay